# Maximize area of rectangle inside a triangle

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the maximum area of a rectangle that is inside of the triangle forms by the x-axis and the lines y=-3x+12 and y=3x+12. The base of the triangle is on the x-axis and the two upper verticies are on the lines y=-3x+12 and y=3x+12.

With this question. Obviously the are of the rectangle is l*w or x*y... I have figured out that x = (8-2x) and y=(12-y). Im not sure of the next step.. Could someone help?

Comment: If you really have $x=8-2x$ and $y=12-y$ then you have $x=8/3$ and $y=6$, but where did you get those two equations?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

The two lines are symmetric across the $y$-axis. Therefore, just take twice the area in the 1st quadrant.

Thus the area of the rectangle (width times height) is $2x(-3x+12) = -6x^2+24x$, where $0 ≤ x ≤ 4$.

Since the quadratic is concave up, notice that the maximum is at $x = -\frac{b}{2a} = -\frac{24}{2(-6)} = 2$, which gives the maximum area as $-6(2)^2 + 24(2) = \boxed{24}$.